# Configuring Drupal with a dynamic IP address

Tags: uri

I have now a problem with the multisite configuration of Drupal 7 installed on my linux machine.
I want this site to be accessible from outsite from my local machine. For this I have a domain name from no-ip, that redirects the requests to my machine, and a multisite Drupal 7 configuration.
When I check the configuration, I am facing the result below:

- I can access the non-drupal sites with no problem from the linux
  machine using the mydomain.no-ip.org address.
- I can access the drupal sites with no problem from the linux machine using the local network address (192.168.1....).
- I ****CAN'T**** correctly access the drupal sites (drupalsite1, drupalsite2) from the linux machine using the local network address.
   This is the problem: I am redirected to the main drupal site, although I request the drupalsite1.

And, for information, I can't access the linux machine from my W7 other machine using the mydomain.no-ip.org address (I have the STB interface). All is right with local addresses.


It seems that Drupal doesn't recognize the specified drupal site I want to get, and then redirects me to the default main drupal site.
Has somebody any idea?
May I get any example of Drupal configuration working with a dynip or no-ip service?

I am quite newbie in D7.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use external DNS when working locally on a development box.

You can add the required mapping to your `/etc/hosts` file

e.g:

```
127.0.0.1 drupalsite1 drupalsite2 drupalsite3
```

Then you can access the site by visting, e.g `http://drupalsite1` in your browser

You could even use something like

```
127.0.0.1 drupalsite1.no-ip.org drupalsite2.no-ip.org
```

If you'd prefer.

The `/etc/hosts` file is checked prior to external DNS lookup and will override / take precedence over the latter. There's a similar file in Windows as well.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: Thanks, but I want my site to be accessible outside from my local linux machine, so I need a dns and dynip redirection.

As I have added above, it seems that the drupal doesn't recognize the site I want to get.


When restarting apache, I can't get ride of the 'apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1 for ServerName' warning message.
I have many other sites, and there can be various causes.
I have tried all what you say, but it still doesn't work.

Thank you for your answer anyway. I am still investigating.

Comment: @Jerome, sounds like you need to configure your virtual host further, e.g add each site as a `ServerAlias` You can also use [sites.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/sites%21example.sites.php/7) for mapping domain names to multisite subfolders.